# Launch scripts before starting spring boot embedded tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I created an executable jar using spring boot 1.4 and am using embedded tomcat.
We have some scripts inside a bat file,we need to run that bat file before launching tomcat.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could execute script on command line runner interface.

```
    public class Application  implements CommandLineRunner{

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }

        @Override
        public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
           // Call the batch script here
        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a valid answer but I would want to verify that the CommandLineRunner is called before the Tomcat is started up as you question specifically stated that you need the scripts to execute before it starts.